# Overriding parts of a webapp's web.xml in Tomcat (eg manager application max file upload size)

Tags: debian, tomcat

I am running the Tomcat manager application via a Debian package (`tomcat8-admin`), which deploys the webapp from `/usr/share/tomcat8-admin/manager`. We ran into a problem hitting the maximum upload size (configured as the `multipart-config` element in the `HTMLManager` `servlet` block). This is easy to fix if you're willing to edit Debian-packaged files, but this is incorrect: files in `/usr/share` are owned exclusively by `dpkg`. Is there a way to override this element from somewhere in tomcat's conf directory (which is symlinked to `/etc/tomcat8` in Debian)?

Searching for this problem on the web only results in suggestions about editing `web.xml` directly (eg http://www.giantgeek.com/blog/?p=1000) or about different programming approaches using context parameters (if I understand correctly; I'm not especially familiar with the jargon).

If it's not possible to override this at the moment, then I'd be interested in suggestions about the best place to file a bug: is it that `web.xml` shouldn't contain site-specific options, as I have read - in which case does the fault lie with Tomcat? Or is the Debian packaging faulty, and should `web.xml` be made into a config file and symlinked from `/etc`?

Of course I could maintain a local version of the Debian package with this overriden, but for such an apparently-obvious piece of configuration that seems wrong too.

Answer (score -1):

You can install tomcat without dpkg. Also which folder you want. Some googling can help. After that make multipart conf in web.xml.

Comment: Downvoting because this doesn't answer the question or contain any useful information. Sorry.